# Is a Highwire Eruv allowed?

Tags: halacha, electricity, eruv-chatzerot

Where can I found the discussion regarding the permissibility of using the hotwire/highwire (the electric wire which is all the way at the top of the utility pole) as part of the Eruv? Thanks
The issue is as follows:
The high wire doesn't pass directly above the utility pole, rather there is an extension that continues upward along the side of the pole and reaches pass the top of the pole, and it is that extension which is holding the high wire.
as this

[image: this]

The high wire is on top of that extension. To be clear, the extension continues parrralel along the pole and continues above the pile, the extension is not perpendicular to the pole.The issue is whether the amud of the tzuras hapesach has to be straight, or could the abutment be considered as part of the amud.
Adding a lechi along the hight of the pole to end under the abutment is not an option, being that it is so high up and the city does not allow anyone to get anywhere near the hotwire. I'm asking in a case of a shas hadchak, if bideved one can rely on the hotwire.

Comment: As you see on the design, you need to make an additional column under the wire.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the extension continues parrralel along the pole"?

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna Berurah [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=51&hilite=) 362 s.v. 64 quotes a number of tshuvos that discuss telegraph wires. He does not write what they say, but he does say see there, implying you should rule with those opinions.

You will find they all did not allow it for the issue you mention.

Sho'el Umeishiv also addressed the fact that the tzuras hapesach was not made specifically for that purpose, but decided that is not a necessary criteria. Chazzon Ish writes the same.

The seffer Binas Simcha quotes Rav Grainman
as saying the telegraph wires they are discussing had the wires hanging close by the side of the pole. Modern day electric wires are even worse being that the wires are even further out from the side of the pole. This can be found in the Dirshu edition of M.B. That footnote goes on to say he discuses whether adding a lechi would help in this situation. He also points to Minchas Yitzchok vol 1 #59 on the subject.

Comment: Worth noting there have been lenient opinions on this issue, though they aren't that popular nowadays.

Comment: That would be worth noting. I just don't have any sources for that at the moment. Feel free to edit or add a parallel answer.